# How to exclude unnecessary commits from a pull request?

Tags: git, github

I faced a problem using git branch. I sent PR to merge the develop branch to the master branch, but it included unnecessary commits. I'd like to remove these from PR.

1. I created the develop branch from the master branch, and I added D1, D2 commits. Finally, I merged the develop branch to the master using 'squash and merge'.
2. And I created a feature branch from the develop branch, and I added F1, F2 commits.
3. In the meantime, another person added M4 commit to the master branch.
4. I sent a pull request to merge the feature branch to master. However, this PR included D1, D2, F1, and F2 commits.

I had to create the feature branch from master. It was my mistake :(

```
 ───M1───M2───M3───S────M4 (master)
    └────D1───D2───┘ (develop)
              └────F1───F2 (feature)
```

How do I include only F1 and F2 commits except for D1 and D2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rene's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54615767/1256452) is correct, but all of these slightly-fancy (box-character-set-using) diagrams are a bit off, starting with your own:

> ```
> ───M1───M2───M3───S────M4 (master)
>    └────D1───D2───┘ (develop)
>              └────F1───F2 (feature)
> ```

The reason is this:

> ... I merged the develop branch to the master using 'squash and merge'.

The "squash and merge" button on clicky GUIs, or `git merge --squash` on the command line, makes a new commit that *is not a merge*.  Instead of:

```
...--M1--M2--M3--S--M4   <-- master
      \         /
       D1-----D2   <-- develop
```

what you actually got was:

```
...--M1--M2--M3--S--M4   <-- master
       \
        D1--D2   <-- develop
```

There is no ancestor/descendant relationship between `S` and any of the `D`s, nor between any `M` but `M1` and any of the `D`s.  This is just what trips up later Git operations.  If you make an actual merge—using plain `git merge`, or `git merge --no-ff`, or a non-squashy GitHub clicky button, *then* `S` (and therefore `M4` as well) would be descendants of `D1` and `D2`.

But that's not what we have.  So when we look at `feature` and `master`, we see this:

```
...--M1--M2--M3--S--M4   <-- master
       \
        D1--D2--F1--F2   <-- feature
```

We see that `feature` has *four* commits reachable from its tip commit (including the tip commit itself) that are not reachable from `master`, namely `D1-D2-F1-F1`.  Whether or not there is some name pointing to `D2`, these four commits *are* the four that are on `feature` that are not also on `master`.  (Commit `M1` is on *both* branches, as is everything to its left.)

I think a good way to think of this is that "squash merge" has the side effect of *killing off* the branch that was just merged.  Commits `D1` and `D2` are now, in effect, "dead" and must be considered at least mildly radioactive.  As [Ahmad Khundaqji said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54615032/1256452), they will often be harmless in the end.  But they can make your commit history look ugly—as in *why was this committed twice, once as two separate commits and later as one bigger one?* if `feature` is actually-merged instead of squash-"merged"—and at worst, they can cause conflicts later, due to some change in a commit that is a descendant of `S`.

Since the merged branch is now "dead" it should be deleted.  That is, you should run `git branch -D develop`.  But before doing so, make sure commits `D1` and `D2` are not themselves contained in any other branches—which of course, in your case, they *are*.  If they *are* contained in other branches, you must reconstruct those branches as variants that no longer have those two commits.

Note that "rebase and merge" (another clicky button on GitHub—actually all three are combined into one button with an internal dropdown, but that's merely a way of expressing three different buttons) *also* has the side effect of killing off branches, since rebase really means *copy old commits to new ones, then stop using the old commits in favor of the new copies*.

I would draw the post-`git rebase --onto master develop feature` graph this way, keeping the "dead" `develop` in the picture:

```
                       F1'-F2'  <-- feature
                      /
...--M1--M2--M3--S--M4   <-- master
       \
        D1--D2   <-- develop
              \
               F1--F2   [abandoned]
```

This makes it clearer that `F1` and `F2` *still exist* under their unique commit hash IDs.  They are just no longer *easy to find* as there is no name we can use to find them.<sup>1</sup>  Starting from the name `feature`, we first find the replacement copy `F2'` that we are to use instead of `F2`, then `F1'` that we should use in place of `F1`, then `M4`, then `S`, and so on, backwards into the past.  Git commands like `git log` won't find the old dull commits that we've replaced with shiny new ones that descend from `F2'` instead of from `M1`.

(And, *now* it's safe to delete `develop`, as long as no other branches *also* include `D1`.  Note that including `D2` automatically includes `D1` so that's the only one we need to mention here.)

In the long-form `git rebase --onto master develop feature` command, we have three interesting arguments (plus the option keyword `--onto` of course).  Starting from the end and working backwards, as Git is [wont](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wont) to do, we have:

- `feature` as an extra argument, which [the `git rebase` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) calls `[<branch>]`: tells `git rebase` to start by doing `git checkout feature`.  If you do this yourself you can leave off that last argument.  This is literally just passed to `git checkout`,<sup>2</sup> so it should always be a branch name.
- `develop` as what the `git rebase` documentation calls `[<upstream>]`: tells `git rebase` which commits *not* to copy.  If you omit this argument, Git uses whatever is configured as the target (or current) branch's *upstream*.  This name is passed through [`git rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse), so it can be almost anything: a raw hash ID, a tag name, `git describe` output, a branch name, a relative operation like `HEAD~2`, and so on.
- `--onto master` as what the `git rebase` documentation calls `<newbase>`: tells `git rebase` *where to put the commit copies*, which ultimately directs it where to re-point the branch, once the copying is complete.  If you leave this out, it defaults to `<upstream>`, and like `<upstream>` it is passed through `git rev-parse`.

So this command-line `git rebase` command means:

> > After checking out `feature`, copy all commits reachable from the branch's tip, excluding any commits that are also reachable from the commit identified by `develop`, and  also excluding any other commits that you, `git rebase`, feel the need to omit.<sup>3</sup>  Do the copies in the correct topologically-sorted order so that earlier, less-dependent commits are copied first, and later, more-dependent commits are copied later.  Place each copy such that the *first* copied commit comes immediately after the commit identified by `master`.  When you have copied the last commit, yank the branch name `feature` around so that it points to the last copied commit, or if no commits get copied, directly to the commit identified by `master`.

When Git has finished doing this, you end up with commits that look the way we drew them.  (You are also on branch `feature`, unless the Git folks have fixed what I consider a minor bug in `git rebase`—it seems like if you tell rebase to start by doing `git checkout feature`, but you're on, say, `master`, it should leave you on `master` in the end, not on `feature`.  Of course, if the rebase has to stop with conflicts, it stops in "detached HEAD" mode, but when you `git rebase --continue` or `git rebase --abort` to resume or terminate the operation, it should eventually put you back where you were, even if that's *not* `feature`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>There *are* names by which you can find the original `F2` and `F1`, stored in Git's *reflogs*.  The reflog for any reference name, including those for branch names, contains a log of which commits that branch-name identified, by their hash IDs, as of some particular time-stamp.  Every update to a ref, done by `git update-ref refs/heads/feature` for instance, keeps the *previous* value in the reflog and adds the *new* value with the time-stamp of when that new value was just written (and a reflog message as to what's going on).

Run `git reflog feature` to see the reflog entries for `refs/heads/feature`.  There is an additional reflog for `HEAD` itself.  Run `git reflog` or `git reflog HEAD` to see that one.  Note that old entries eventually expire; for more on this, see the `git reflog expire` sub-command and [the `git reflog` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

Note that `git reflog show`—this is the sub-command you're using here—really just runs `git log -g`, so you can use `git log -g` instead of `git reflog` here.

Deleting any branch deletes its reflog, but the entries in the `HEAD` reflog remain.  There are plans to save the reflogs from deleted branches in some future Git version, in the service of being able to "undelete" a branch, but those plans are rather wooly and unfocused as yet, and have some issues with implementation.

<sup>2</sup>At one point the word *literally* here was literally correct, as `git rebase` was a big shell script.  But now many parts of `git rebase` are written in C.  The `git checkout` command is also written in C, and when you build Git, you build binaries that share some of the back-end implementation code.  If `git rebase` is C code that calls the same back-end code as an otherwise-separate `git checkout` binary, is that *literally* calling `git checkout`, or is it now *figurative?*  What are the correct semantics of the word *literal* here?  Should *literal* require matching front-ends as well as back-ends, or matching back-ends only?

<sup>3</sup>The commits that `git rebase` omits on its own are:

- Merge commits.  These are literally impossible to copy.  In some modes, `git rebase` will *re-perform* merges as needed.  These modes are the old `--preserve-merges` and the newfangled, improved `--rebase-merges`; both are tricky and I'm not going to attempt to describe them here.
- Commits in other side of the symmetric difference with the same patch-ID.  That is, while the rebase documentation talks about finding the list of commits to copy with `<upstream>..HEAD`, it actually uses `<upstream>...HEAD` to find the symmetric difference of the two sets of commits: those reachable from `HEAD` but not from the upstream argument, and those reachable from the upstream argument but not from `HEAD`.

This last part uses the `git rev-list --left-right` command's ability to distinguish which "side" such commits come from: the commits that *can* be copied are on the right—reachable from `HEAD` but not from `<upstream>`.  However, the ones that are on the left side of this symmetric difference are those "past the cutoff point" but reachable from `<upstream>`.  In this particular situation, these commits are `S` itself and `M4`.  So Git computes a patch ID for those two commits, using `git patch-id`.  It also computes a patch ID for each of the candidates to copy—in this case `F1` and `F2`.  If the patch IDs of any of the copying candidates match those of any in the other half, Git concludes they must have already been cherry-picked into `<upstream>` and should be omitted during copying.

This conclusion is *usually* correct, but in some cases, it can be wrong!  **It's always a good idea to test the result of any of Git's automated operations.**  The way it goes wrong is, for instance, if one commit fixes a stray `}` on a line by itself, and there is *another* stray `}` on a line by itself in the upstream series.  These two fixes are on *different source lines* and may have *different indentation* as well, but to `git patch-id`, they are the *same change*, as the patch ID is constructed by removing the line numbers and some of the white space.

Answer (score 2):

Because you did a squash merge with your first PR, Git does not know that D1 and D2 are already included in the *master* branch.

You need to `rebase --onto` your feature branch to the (latest) commit of the *master* branch:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase develop --onto master
```

The result will look like this:

```
───M1───M2───M3───S────────────M4 (master)
    └────D1───D2──┘ (develop)   └────F1───F2 (feature)
```

Now you can `push --force` your feature branch and update your PR. Or close the old PR and create a new one with the current feature branch.

BTW: From you branch names I assume you are using a kind of GitFlow branching model. In this model you shouldn't merge the *develop* branch into the *master* with a squash merge, because you will always have this issue with already merged commits.

Comment: What does `rebase develop --onto master` mean? I think it's 'moving HEAD of the develop branch to M4', is it right?

Comment: No. It copies the commits `F1` and `F2` on top of *master*  the sets the HEAD of the *feature* branch to the new `F2`commit, see https://git-scm.com/book/de/v1/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Answer (score 0):

as long as the D1, D2 changes is already merged into the master there will be no problem sending them over again through a new pull request (D1, D2 won't be considered changes)

However, you need in your case to Rebase your Develop Branch with M1 Commit, so that your PR is updated with everything, and GIT detects F1 and F2 as new things only.

- Or

The easiest way, is just to create a PR from Master to Develop, and have it merged after you pull out the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Ask author of PR to create another branch of latest master (or destination branch in your repository)

Author must cherry pick required commits and do squash if needed and commit

Author sends a fresh PR